# Is Outlook.pst a complete and safe backup of gmail emails through imap?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

I have set up my Microsoft Outlook to receive gmail through imap protocols. I backed up these emails in a pst file `Outlook.pst`. Suppose I delete all the emails in my gmail account. Will the emails backed up in Outlook.pst disappear after imap synchronisation? Is `Outlook.pst` a complete and safe backup of my past emails in gmail?

I am using Microsoft Office 2016.

EDIT: I have done some testing and it seems the emails are safe in Outlook.pst. Asking here for further confirmation.

Comment: What happened when you did some testing? Delete some unimportant emails from gmail and see what happens?

Comment: @DavidPostill, so far it seems the emails in Outlook.pst are still intact. However, I wanted further confirmation. So, I decided to ask the people here. Emails are very precious nowadays.

Comment: Nothing is completely safe.  If you archive emails in a .pst, it's as safe as any other file, and subject to the same risks as any other file.  If the messages are deleted from gmail, that will be your only copy.  To keep it safe, make one or more backups of the .pst and keep those on other drives.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? Why the multiple negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook.pst file is an additional PST file that used for backup, not the default data file you are using with your Gmail account in Outlook, correct? Theoretically, your emails should stay intact in this situation. PST files are local data file which will not sync with the mail server.  Besides, do not store the PST file to a network path as it may get corrupted due to some unexpected reasons.